# Track Knowledge Article Views by User in Apex

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, community, custom-object, knowledge

Do you know how to obtain the articles viewed by each user in my community? I would not like to create a custom object because I would have many records.
I would like to add this functionality to my component and mark the views

[image]

Comment: total amount of views an article has OR amount of views by current user?

Comment: @glls Specifically, what articles in the community have been seen by each user